# Confused whether to use AFTER or OF in these given sentence

Tags: prepositions

Kindly consider this sentence

***I hired a taxi from the airport within minutes after arrival to reach home as soon as possible.***

I just want to know whether I should use **within minutes after arrival** or **within minutes of arrival**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really matter. *Of* can mean either *after* or *before* in this context. Most people will assume *after*. If you want to make it clear that you hired a taxi before you arrived, you will need to be explicit:

> I hired a taxi from the airport before I arrived in order to reach home as soon as possible.

As another user pointed out, *within minutes of* is colloquial, but *within minutes after* isn't. It would be better to just use *minutes after*, instead.